# How to assertRaises(ValidationError) against Django Rest Framework APIView?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

eg. I have my view:

```py
class MyView(APIView):
    def post(...):
        ...
        raise ValidationError('blah')
```

And to my test

```py
def test_myview(...):
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    request = factory.post('/myview', data=...)
    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
        MyView.as_view()(request)
```

I get `AssertionError: ValidationError not raised`

I tried to call it and print the result of the call:

```py
def test_myview(...):
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    request = factory.post('/myview', data=...)
    resp = MyView.as_view()(request)
    print(resp)
```

it's `<Response status_code=400, "text/html; charset=utf-8">`, so it's kind of correct if I want to test the response code etc, but what should I do if I want to assertRaises instead?

Comment: Yeah I figured it would be the way

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the response details (which suppose to contain ‘blah’) if you are looking for asserting the validation error message.

DRF handles the exception and returns 400, that’s why you can’t really see it in your unit test. See [django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions](https://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions)